# Curl requests in python

Tags: python, curl, request

I have a curl request like this:

```
curl -X POST http://mdom-n-plus-1.nonprod.appsight.us:8081/mesmerdom/v3/getByImageAndDom -F "data=$DATA" -F "dom=@$DOM" -F "image=@$IMG"
```

I am trying to convert it to python by using something like this:

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://mdom-n-plus-1.nonprod.appsight.us:8081/mesmerdom/v1/getByScreen"
payload = {"data": json.dumps({"screen":["screen-id", "57675"]}), dom:"abc", image:"xyz"}
req = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print (req.text)
```

but it is not working.

Comment: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: `image` is supposed to be a file upload, not a string